# Equivalence between Newton's shell theorem for a point inside the sphere and Kepler's second law?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion

I am trying to understand the shell theorem and as part of simplifying it for my understanding, came up with this diagram :  [image: attempted-shell-theorem-simplification].

It looks rather similar to an illustration of kepler's second law as [image: seen here].

So for my question, does kepler's second law imply (or is a corollary) the shell-theorem for a point within the sphere?

Am I wrong in drawing comparison's between the two? If yes, then in what way?

Edit (Post accepting answer) :
I guess this should have been my primary question, but still - is my simplification of the shell theorem correct?

[image: shell-theorem-inside-sphere]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, these proofs have nothing to do with each other. Kepler's second law follows solely from angular momentum conservation and works in any number of dimensions, for any central force. The shell theorem requires an inverse square force in three spatial dimensions.

To put it more simply, Kepler's second law isn't about spheres at all -- it's about orbits.